# python selenium webdriver verify sent gmail

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, gmail

Python selenium Gmail automation.
Compose and send the mail.
Verify whether email sent successfully.
Verify whether it is present in sent box.

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Sent").click()
emails = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//tr[@role="row"]')))
time.sleep(5)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)
for email in emails:
    if email.text == "To: prasannakpechu@gmail.com Subject: demo":
        print("Email sent successfully")
        break
else:
    print("Email not found in sent folder, sending may have failed")
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Log in to gmail - completed
Compose email - completed

getting error while automating email sent successfully and present in sent box.

Comment: please provide some code which you have already tried.

Comment: getting error while validating email has been sent successfully or not.
followed by mail present in sent box or not.